# How can I transform this logical if-then constraint?

Tags: modeling, logical-constraints

I want to know how to transform this logical if-then constraint? If $B=1$,then $A \ge C$, else $A=0$, where $A$ and $B$ are decision variables and $C$ are constants. $B$ is binary variable and $A\ge 0$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linear Programming with additional "if-then"/"Default to zero" constraints?](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/1512/linear-programming-with-additional-if-then-default-to-zero-constraints)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For better readability, let $y_B \in \{0,1\}$ be your $B$ variable, and let $x_A \in \mathbb{R}^+$ be your $A$ variable. You can model your statement as follows:

$$
 Cy_B \le x_A \le My_B
$$

$M$ is an upper bound for variable $x_A$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer is really fantastic! Here is my answer, it is more complex and nonlinear. (y_B-1) * x_A=0, M+x_A-C >= M*y_B, where y_B is binary and M is a large positive number.